# How can i make this thread model?

Tags: modeling

I tried to make this model but did not get any success with the shape. I tried with the tissue addon. But did not get the shape. Any way to create the shape of the mode.

[image]

[image]

I tried so far. Any suggestion. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to create one segment. Use a *Mirror* modifier to make it easier. It should look like that:

[image]

Give it a *Solidify* modifier, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to link-duplicate in order to see if it works, make the necessary modifications in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Once you are good, give it an *Array* modifier in order to repeat:

[image]

Blend file: [image]

Comment: can i get the file plz. so view to close whats going on with the shape. Thanks

Comment: sure, I'm going to give a link, it's not finished of course